# What is the @var annotation for in a Doctrine entity in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Perhaps a silly question but it bugs me that I don't know ...

When I create an entity with `app/console doctrine:generate:entity` it adds an `@var` annotation to each property.  What is `@var` used for?

It obviously indicates the data type but I don't see it mentioned in any documentation and things seems to work whether it's there or not so I just wonder what uses it.

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a standard [phpdoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) comment. It has nothing to do with Doctrine annotations, and they are ignored by Doctrine. They are used when generating documentation and also as metadata for IDE's that support code completion.