# Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Users could not be converted to string

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship, symfony-2.7

I am new to symfony and doctrine. I have 2 entities in doctrine one is Users and other is ActivityLogs here is the classes.

**Users.php**

```
<?php
    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
    * Users
    *
    * @ORM\Table(name="ms_users")
    * @ORM\Entity
    */
    class Users
    {
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="verification_tokken", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $verificationTokken;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tokken_expiry_time", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $tokkenExpiryTime;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_two_way_auth_enabled", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isTwoWayAuthEnabled;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="verification_pin", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $verificationPin;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=250)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_string", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $dateString;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_time_string", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $dateTimeString;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="integer")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_deleted", type="integer")
     */
    private $isDeleted;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_editable", type="integer")
     */
    private $isEditable;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_updated_on", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $lastUpdatedOn;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="school_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $schoolId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_by", type="integer")
     */
    private $updatedBy;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set verificationTokken
     *
     * @param string $verificationTokken
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setVerificationTokken($verificationTokken)
    {
        $this->verificationTokken = $verificationTokken;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get verificationTokken
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVerificationTokken()
    {
        return $this->verificationTokken;
    }

    /**
     * Set tokkenExpiryTime
     *
     * @param string $tokkenExpiryTime
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setTokkenExpiryTime($tokkenExpiryTime)
    {
        $this->tokkenExpiryTime = $tokkenExpiryTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tokkenExpiryTime
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTokkenExpiryTime()
    {
        return $this->tokkenExpiryTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set isTwoWayAuthEnabled
     *
     * @param integer $isTwoWayAuthEnabled
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setIsTwoWayAuthEnabled($isTwoWayAuthEnabled)
    {
        $this->isTwoWayAuthEnabled = $isTwoWayAuthEnabled;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isTwoWayAuthEnabled
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getIsTwoWayAuthEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isTwoWayAuthEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * Set verificationPin
     *
     * @param string $verificationPin
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setVerificationPin($verificationPin)
    {
        $this->verificationPin = $verificationPin;

        return $this;
    }

        /**
     * Get verificationPin
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVerificationPin()
    {
        return $this->verificationPin;
    }

    /**
     * Set slug
     *
     * @param string $slug
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setSlug($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get slug
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateString
     *
     * @param string $dateString
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setDateString($dateString)
    {
        $this->dateString = $dateString;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateString
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDateString()
    {
        return $this->dateString;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateTimeString
     *
     * @param string $dateTimeString
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setDateTimeString($dateTimeString)
    {
        $this->dateTimeString = $dateTimeString;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateTimeString
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDateTimeString()
    {
        return $this->dateTimeString;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param integer $isActive
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Set isDeleted
     *
     * @param integer $isDeleted
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setIsDeleted($isDeleted)
    {
        $this->isDeleted = $isDeleted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isDeleted
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getIsDeleted()
    {
        return $this->isDeleted;
    }

    /**
     * Set isEditable
     *
     * @param integer $isEditable
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setIsEditable($isEditable)
    {
        $this->isEditable = $isEditable;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isEditable
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getIsEditable()
    {
        return $this->isEditable;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastUpdatedOn
     *
     * @param string $lastUpdatedOn
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setLastUpdatedOn($lastUpdatedOn)
    {
        $this->lastUpdatedOn = $lastUpdatedOn;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastUpdatedOn
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastUpdatedOn()
    {
        return $this->lastUpdatedOn;
    }

    /**
     * Set schoolId
     *
     * @param integer $schoolId
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setSchoolId($schoolId)
    {
        $this->schoolId = $schoolId;

        return $this;
    }

   /**
     * Get schoolId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getSchoolId()
    {
        return $this->schoolId;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedBy
     *
     * @param integer $updatedBy
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUpdatedBy($updatedBy)
    {
        $this->updatedBy = $updatedBy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedBy
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getUpdatedBy()
    {
        return $this->updatedBy;
    }
}
```

**AcitivityLogs.php**

```
<?php

    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * ActivitLogs
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="ms_activity_logs")
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class ActivitLogs
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
         * 
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $userId;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="activity_log", type="text")
         */
        private $activityLog;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="user_agent", type="string", length=250)
         */
        private $userAgent;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="os_platform", type="string", length=250)
         */
        private $osPlatform;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="ip_address", type="string", length=250)
         */
        private $ipAddress;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="referer", type="text")
         */
        private $referer;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="date_string", type="string", length=50)
         */
        private $dateString;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="date_time_string", type="string", length=50)
         */
        private $dateTimeString;

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="integer")
         */
        private $isActive;

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="is_deleted", type="integer")
         */
        private $isDeleted;

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="is_editable", type="integer")
         */
        private $isEditable;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="last_updated_on", type="string", length=50)
         */
        private $lastUpdatedOn;

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="school_id", type="integer")
         */
        private $schoolId;

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="updated_by", type="integer")
         */
        private $updatedBy;


        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set userId
         *
         * @param integer $userId
         *
         * @return ActivitLogs
         */
        public function setUserId($userId)
        {
            $this->userId = $userId;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get userId
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getUserId()
        {
            return $this->userId;
        }

        /**
         * Set activityLog
         *
         * @param string $activityLog
         *
         * @return ActivitLogs
         */
        public function setActivityLog($activityLog)
        {
            $this->activityLog = $activityLog;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get activityLog
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getActivityLog()
        {
            return $this->activityLog;
        }

        /**
         * Set userAgent
         *
         * @param string $userAgent
         *
         * @return ActivitLogs
         */
        public function setUserAgent($userAgent)
        {
            $this->userAgent = $userAgent;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get userAgent
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getUserAgent()
        {
            return $this->userAgent;
        }

        /**
         * Set osPlatform
         *
         * @param string $osPlatform
         *
         * @return ActivitLogs
         */
        public function setOsPlatform($osPlatform)
        {
            $this->osPlatform = $osPlatform;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get osPlatform
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getOsPlatform()
        {
            return $this->osPlatform;
        }

        /**
         * Set ipAddress
         *
         * @param string $ipAddress
         *
         * @return ActivitLogs
         */
        public function setIpAddress($ipAddress)
        {
            $this->ipAddress = $ipAddress;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get ipAddress
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getIpAddress()
        {
            return $this->ipAddress;
        }

        /**
         * Set referer
         *
         * @param string $referer
         *
         * @return ActivitLogs
         */
        public function setReferer($referer)
        {
            $this->referer = $referer;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get referer
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getReferer()
        {
            return $this->referer;
        }

        /**
         * Set dateString
         *
         * @param string $dateString
         *
         * @return ActivitLogs
         */
        public function setDateString($dateString)
        {
            $this->dateString = $dateString;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get dateString
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getDateString()
        {
            return $this->dateString;
        }

        /**
         * Set dateTimeString
         *
         * @param string $dateTimeString
         *
         * @return ActivitLogs
         */
        public function setDateTimeString($dateTimeString)
        {
            $this->dateTimeString = $dateTimeString;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get dateTimeString
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getDateTimeString()
        {
            return $this->dateTimeString;
        }

        /**
         * Set isActive
         *
         * @param integer $isActive
         *
         * @return ActivitLogs
         */
        public function setIsActive($isActive)
        {
            $this->isActive = $isActive;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get isActive
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getIsActive()
        {
            return $this->isActive;
        }

        /**
         * Set isDeleted
         *
         * @param integer $isDeleted
         *
         * @return ActivitLogs
         */
        public function setIsDeleted($isDeleted)
        {
            $this->isDeleted = $isDeleted;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get isDeleted
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getIsDeleted()
        {
            return $this->isDeleted;
        }

        /**
         * Set isEditable
         *
         * @param integer $isEditable
         *
         * @return ActivitLogs
         */
        public function setIsEditable($isEditable)
        {
            $this->isEditable = $isEditable;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get isEditable
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getIsEditable()
        {
            return $this->isEditable;
        }

        /**
         * Set lastUpdatedOn
         *
         * @param string $lastUpdatedOn
         *
         * @return ActivitLogs
         */
        public function setLastUpdatedOn($lastUpdatedOn)
        {
            $this->lastUpdatedOn = $lastUpdatedOn;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get lastUpdatedOn
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getLastUpdatedOn()
        {
            return $this->lastUpdatedOn;
        }

        /**
         * Set schoolId
         *
         * @param integer $schoolId
         *
         * @return ActivitLogs
         */
        public function setSchoolId($schoolId)
        {
            $this->schoolId = $schoolId;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get schoolId
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getSchoolId()
        {
            return $this->schoolId;
        }

        /**
         * Set updatedBy
         *
         * @param integer $updatedBy
         *
         * @return ActivitLogs
         */
        public function setUpdatedBy($updatedBy)
        {
            $this->updatedBy = $updatedBy;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get updatedBy
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getUpdatedBy()
        {
            return $this->updatedBy;
        }
    }
```

I have a simple ManyToOne Relationship between these two tables on userId field.

Here is the code with i m trying to add the data in to database with doctrine.

```
public function checkDatabaseAction(){
            
            $user = new Users();
            $user->setDateString(date('Y-m-d'))
                ->setDateTimeString(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                ->setIsActive(1)
                ->setIsDeleted(0)
                ->setIsEditable(1)
                ->setIsTwoWayAuthEnabled(0)
                ->setLastUpdatedOn(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                ->setSchoolId(1)
                ->setSlug('abc-123')
                ->setTokkenExpiryTime(date('Y-m-d'))
                ->setUpdatedBy(1)
                ->setUsername('ahmedali5530')
                ->setVerificationPin('1122')
                ->setVerificationTokken('hskajdhfkjlh435kh34k5jh435');
            
            $log = new ActivitLogs();
            $log->setActivityLog('A log')
                ->setDateString(date('Y-m-d'))
                ->setDateTimeString(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                ->setIpAddress('192.168.1.16')
                ->setIsActive(1)
                ->setIsDeleted(0)
                ->setIsEditable(1)
                ->setLastUpdatedOn(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                ->setOsPlatform('Windows 7')
                ->setReferer('http://localhost/symfony')
                ->setSchoolId(1)
                ->setUpdatedBy(1)
                ->setUserAgent('Chrome')
                ->setUserId($user);
            
            
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
               
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->persist($log);
            
            
            $em->flush();
            
            $allocateCourses = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:AllocateCourses')->findBy(array('isActive'=>1));
            
            return $this->render(':main:form.html.php',array(
                'data' => $allocateCourses,
            ));
        }
```

When I execute this code I received the error:-

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO ms_activity_logs (user_id, activity_log, user_agent, os_platform, ip_address, referer, date_string, date_time_string, is_active, is_deleted, is_editable, last_updated_on, school_id, updated_by) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [{}, "A log", "Chrome", "Windows 7", "192.168.1.16", "http://localhost/symfony", "2015-12-22", "2015-12-22 16:53:55", 1, 0, 1, "2015-12-22 16:53:55", 1, 1]:
>
> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Users could not be converted to string

Any suggestions how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the answer.

I added the new private property in `ActivityLogs.php` and told Doctrine to generate the entity. Doctrine created getter and setters for that property. This fixed my problem.

Here is the code I added:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="ActivityLogs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

Comment: @Bono, [why did you reject](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12349720) the proposed edit on the vital part of this answer and made many grammer corrections instead? Was the proposed `@var Users[]` wrong?

Comment: @try-catch-finally [They are not actually handled by Doctrine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274560/what-is-the-var-annotation-for-in-a-doctrine-entity-in-symfony), and are therefor not necessary. Granted I could have kept it in. I rejected it, like some of the other reviewers, because "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability." And added changes which I thought to be better (though at that point I agree I could have kept the `@var users` in)